# javafx event propagation on Panes

Tags: javafx, scroll, pane

In my javafx project I have an fxml layout file.

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="anchorPane" fx:controller="plane.splitting.PlaneSplittingController">
<BorderPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <center>
        <ScrollPane>
            <Canvas height="500" width="500" fx:id="canvas"></Canvas>
        </ScrollPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
<BorderPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">

</BorderPane>
```

So I have a Canvas inside ScrollPane in the first BorderPane, and the second BorderPane, which is on the first BorderPane and is preventing scrolling of the ScrollPane when I am trying to scroll it with mouse via scroll bar. How can I solve this problem? I think I need to make the second BorderPane to Propagate all events to first one.

Comment: Your second `BorderPane` is on top of your first `BorderPane` which prevents the latter from receiving mouse events.

Comment: @Slaw thank you, I have noticed that. I have tried MouseTransparent="true", but it makes irresponsible other elements inside second BorderedPane too

Comment: Why not make it so they don't overlap?

Comment: @Slaw I have already merged the two BorderPanes into one.

Comment: That's another solution :) Note that `AnchorPane` can be more hassle than it's worth because you have to absolutely position its children. Using layouts that automatically position and size their children result in a much more responsive UI.